# Orbits of orthogonal vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $f$ and $g$ be two $C^{1}$ vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $\langle f(x), g(x) \rangle = 0 \,\,\,\forall \,\, x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. If $f$ admits a cyclic orbit, prove that $g$ possesses a singularity.

I am pretty sure that the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem is used here, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the image of the embedding $S^1 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ which is a cyclic orbit of $f$. By the Schonflies theorem, $C$ is the boundary of an embedded disc $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. The vector field $g(x)$ is defined on $D$ and is orthogonal to $D$.

**Edited for more detail:** The Poincare-Hopf index theorem applies in any situation of a compact manifold $M$ and a vector field on $M$ orthogonal to the boundary, with the conclusion that if $g(x)$ has isolated zeroes then the sum of their indices must be the Euler characteristic of $M$.

Since in this case $M=D$ has Euler characteristic $1$, either $g(x)$ has a non-isolated zero or it has isolated zeroes including one of nonzero index. In either case, $g(x)$ has a zero.

Comment: What do you mean by $g$ being orthogonal to $D$? Also, both theorems you mentioned were not presented during the couse, so I suppose I cannot use them. Thanks anyway

Comment: $D$ is a $C^1$-curve. At the point $x \in D$ the vector $f(x)$ is tangent to $D$, and the vector $g(x)$ is orthogonal to $D$. So, as a shortcut, one says that $g(x)$ is orthogoal to $D$ (at the point $x$). It is similar to the shortcut where we say that the tangent vector $f(x)$ is parallel to $D$ at $x$.

Comment: Ok. But I still don't understand how the Poicaré-Hopf Thorem can be applied there.

Comment: I added more details about how to apply the Poincare-Hopf theorem.